VS Code stopped auto-importing locally exported functions in git-ignored files
A couple of weeks ago, VS Code stopped auto-importing (cmd + .) locally exported functions in git-ignored files.
I have a test.ts file that I use for testing, which is git-ignored. Previously, I could type a function name, trigger auto-complete, and VS Code would suggest the correct import. Now, it only suggests defining the function.
The import sometimes works, mainly for import from packages rather than locally exported functions, but it's highly inconsistent.
If I type the same function name in a file within the same directory that is not git-ignored, the auto-import works fine.
Steps I've tried:

Restarting VS Code
Restarting the TypeScript server

These steps did not resolve the issue.
Any thoughts on what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Seems wonky. I tried reproducing your issue, with no success. It works fine for me

Maybe it's not related to the git ignore then. The only difference I can tell from the other files is that project/test.ts (git ignored) does not work, and project/file.ts works. Thank you for trying to reproduce it. I really appreciate it.
